# Installing a Sifteo Cube Program

Tags: c#, mono, sifteo

I am trying to find out how to install a project into the **Sifteo Cubes.** I have managed to create base project that I can be able to run on the **Siftulator**.

My repository of the project can be found here:
https://github.com/trinkermedia/HelloWorldSifteo

It is a basic 'Hello World' program to test the Sifteo Cubes. The program is commonly added through the **SiftDev** application and running it with **MonoDevelop** // *Xamarin*.

The problem is that for some reason **SiftDev** is not connecting to my **Sifteo Base** for the cubes, so I can not upload my program to them. Alternatively, I have noticed that the programs can be uploaded using a **Swiss** install by using an **`.elf`** file as well. So I have successfully uploaded other `.elf` projects from other people on to my cubes. So I assume that the best approach would be to produce an `.elf` file so I can do the same type of install.

### My question is:

- How can I create the `.elf` file so I can do a *Swiss* install of my project?
- Is there any alternative ways to install the Sifteo Project to the cubes?

More info on the Swiss install

https://developers.sifteo.com/docs/SifteoSDK/0.9.8/device_mgmt.html

Answer (score 0):

I know its very late. you can deploy the .elf file on the cubes by connecting the base with the pc.

1. Go to the folder where .elf file is located.
2. swiss install filename.elf

Restart the base and it will appear.